# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Hi I have an application that is build through jenkins with maven and it is having issues with a particular class. This class is an external class imported for use in this project.

The project builds successfully and everything is fine in the IDE but on run time I get a

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

when it trys to run a method from the class. I've checked and the jar this class resides in is on the classpath. It's added as a dependency in my pom.

I already noticed on build output there is a lot of

> Class 'xxxxx' is not accessible through
>   the ClassLoader.

What could be causing this? I'm lost. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The class not being initialised was present when building but not at runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java